# counting number of lines and print it in mars mips

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to count the number of lines in the text file.
the text file contains numbers, characters, and punctuation.
I can print numbers and characters but for punctuation, I can only print only period.
I finished my code but I want to count the number of lines and print it first of output now.

```
while:
  lb $t0, 0($a1) # load base address a[0] of char
  beqz $t0, end #if array reaches /0 end loop
  beq $t0, '\n', print
  beq $t0, 32, print # check if space

print:
  li $v0, 11
  add $a0, $t0, $0 
  syscall
```

I have tried

`beq $t0, '\n', countLine`

`countLine:`
`addi $t1, $t1, 1`
`j print`

but it does not work.
how can I count and print the number of lines in the text file?
any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more code? (Assuming there is more code) your while loop isn't looping, and all your branches end up at print so will just print the first character. You really probably just want to count how many lines there are, and then at the end, print the count ?

Comment: yes! I just want to count how many lines in the text file and print count but I want to print it before printing character.